# GCP: Docker taking up too much of disk space (47%, 69 GB). How to free up disk space?

Tags: docker, hard-drive, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, disk-space-utilization

Out of the **148 GB** disk space of my `Compute Engine Instance`, `/home` folder is taking up only **55 GB** whereas `/var/lib/docker/containers` is taking up a total of **69 GB**, which is too much of disk space usage IMO. How do I free up the disk space used by `docker`?

I tried `docker system prune`, but it is saying `Total reclaimed space: 0B` and is not cleaning up the disk.

Also `docker system df` is showing only **670 MB** space usage as shown below:

```
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              1                   1                   670.4MB             0B (0%)
Containers          1                   1                   0B                  0B
Local Volumes       0                   0                   0B                  0B
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```

Then what is taking up all that space? I am confused.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the command `docker system df` to show what is taking up the most space.

```
docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              19                  3                   15.62GB             9.883GB (63%)
Containers          8                   5                   296.3MB             220B (0%)
Local Volumes       12                  12                  10.78GB             0B (0%)
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```

From there, `docker system prune` *should* clean up unused items. If the items are not cleaned up, its likely because docker still considers them 'in use'. You will need to manually free them up, or use the more aggressive `prune` commands

**Warning**: These commands may do things you don't expect

```
docker system prune --all
docker system prune --volumes #(This may delete data you aren't expecting)
```

Other helpful commands

Images

```
docker image list
docker rm <id of image you wish to delete>
```

Containers

```
docker ps -all
```

Volumes

```
docker volume list
```

Comment: Thanks. `docker system df` is showing only 670 MB space usage. I updated the question to add this information. I don't know why then `/var/lib/docker/containers` take up a total of 69 GB. Weird. :-|

Answer (score 0):

I found a [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27853571/why-is-docker-image-eating-up-my-disk-space-that-is-not-used-by-docker) that might be helpful.

The "$ docker system prune" [command](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/space/) removes all stopped containers, unused networks, dangling images, and build cache.

So I want to believe that if those are not available the command might not work

Comment: This seems to be useful [link](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/1751#issuecomment-475833475)